# How to set a security context for java HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, rest, testing

I am testing HTTP endpoints with HttpUrlConnection:

```
 HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
 httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
 httpCon.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
 httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
 requestHeaders.forEach(httpCon::setRequestProperty);
```

I also add a Basic auth header at the end.

The only problem is that there is a request filter that reads the Principal from the SecurityContext of the request for authorization.
So far I have not found a way to set the SecurityContext and the Principal when using HttpURLConnection.

Is there a way to do so?

Edit:

So the scenario is that there is an embedded Rest Server that serves the requests. I use HttpURLConnection to send requests to a given endpoint. The Rest Server is using basic auth (so I add the credentials in the header), but also does authz check with request filters. This request filter reads the Principal from the request, and does the authz check based on that. I need a way to add the principal to the request I send.

Comment: Hang on: HttpURLConnection is something you would use on a client, while the request filter and principal are things used on a server. What am I missing?

Comment: I added some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To download something that requires authentication, I do

```
public InputStream openStream(URL url, String user, String password) throws IOException {
    if (user != null) {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(user, password));
    }
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    return connection.getInputStream();
}
```

A more up to date answer since Java 11 would be to use the [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) and it's [Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Builder.html). In there you can directly set the authenticator.